# How to change UI Kitten React Native Datepicker background and border colour while using it in React Hook Form Controller without touching the theme?

Tags: react-native, datepicker, react-hook-form, react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to change the colour of the UI Kitten Datepicker's background & border colour without touching the global theme.
I am also using the Datepicker in React Hook Form Controller which seems to not like the Datepicker, however, all other functionality from the Datepicker as worked so far inside it.

No luck so far with using a StyleSheet component both with backdropStyle & style.

What I have so far:

```
<Controller
      as={Datepicker}
      control={control}
      name="date"
      defaultValue={date}
      onSelect={(date: any) => setDatePicker(date)}
      date={dateSearched}
      accessoryLeft={CalendarIcon}
      accessoryRight={resetFormInput}
      backdropStyle={styles.input}
      style={styles.input}
  />
```

Comment: I was able to get some changes by editing the mapping,json file that controls the theme